# when creating dynamic content using jquery ajax, scrollbar not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have some jquery report in which I am creating some dynamic html content (nested divs,span,label) using json.
 Its using jquery,mCustomScrollbar,commons,jqueryui.

I have one `<div>...//some static code </div>` in this case everything works fine.

but when I create some code between this `<div> // dynamic code using ajax  </div>`. Its scrollbar not appearing.

but If I minimize,maximize browser window or 'firebug' the scrollbar appearing.

Is it because of dynamice css style generating?
I am new to jquery css help

Comment: Please narrow this down and try to reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle. It is hard to understand the problem and even more to fix it with so few info.

Comment: Check the DOC of this plugin, all is explained... Luckily, this plugin accepts some kind of delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the scrollbars you refer to are from the `mCustomScrollbar` plugin you will need to use its `update` method once the ajax content is inserted in the DOM.

```
$(selector).mCustomScrollbar("update");
```

See the docs at http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#methods-section

Comment: Or using `live/liveSelector` options

Comment: @A.Wolff i do not think the problem is with new scrollers (*since it is fixed on resize*)..

Comment: I guess OP is already calling update plugin method on window resize. But for sure, i'm just guessing because OP didn't provide enough info in question. EDIT: Oh, i see what you mean now, regarding indeed new content, not new scrollable elements

Comment: @A.Wolff that is handled by the `updateOnContentResize` option and is `true` by default.

Comment: Ya, looks like i misunderstood issue, my bad!

Comment: Thanks Gaby..@GabyakaG.Petrioli what is selector in $(selector)?

Comment: @SanjayRajjadi its is the selector of the element that you have enabled the `mCustomScrollbar` plugin on. (*whatever you use when you first start the plugin*)

Comment: update method didn't work with me because as it's mentioned that updateOnContentResize by default is true which calls update method, I really don't know what is problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved it with a work around by using `destroy` method which is also provided by `mCustomScrollbar`

when I add the new content to the selector I destroy the `mCustomScrollbar`

`$(selector).mCustomScrollbar("destroy");`

then I rebuild it again; you can check destroy and rebuild in this demo

http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/disable_destroy_example.html

BTW `update` method didn't work with me because as it's mentioned that `updateOnContentResize` by default is true which calls update method, I really don't know what is problem.

Comment: Have you found why 'updateOnContentResize' is not working?